# Installation of Ubuntu 18.04 from the .iso file downloaded from the site

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded the .iso file for Ubuntu 18.04, but I don't know how to install it.  The Ubuntu files have created a "DVD" drive (f) but I don't know how to get Ubuntu installed from it.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the ISO file to your PC, you insert a blank/unused DVD into your DVD writer, and you use the "Burn CD" option in Windows to copy the ISO onto the DVD.

You can then take that DVD and insert it into a DVD drive on the destination PC. When you boot that PC, if you have the DVD set as the default 1st boot device, it should read the DVD that you created and start the Ubuntu install process. If you do not have a DVD burner, there is a way to burn the ISO image onto a USB flash drive. You can then boot the target PC from the USB to start the install process.

I believe that you can find detailed instructions and a walk-through with a Google search.